# Can't understand why its not working when using two variables, the same works if i use just a single variable

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char *a,*b;
scanf("%s %s",a,b);
printf("%s %s",a,b);
return 0;
}
```

It works like this,

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(){
    char *a;
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

I think its something with memory becoz when i use malloc and assign some memory it works.

Comment: The `scanf` function doesn't, and can't, allocate memory for the strings. It just uses the uninitialized pointers you pass, to write the strings somewhere. That leads to *undefined behavior*. In *both* cases.

Comment: *"when i use malloc and assign some memory it works"* yes because you have to allocate memory you point to. Your test code working without that is pure accident. Search for *C++ memory tutorial* or similar to teach you the basics. Don't use pointers until you have learned what they do.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Why suggest a C++ memory tutorial instead of a C memory tutorial? :)

Comment: Oh sorry I typed C++ out of reflex - thanks for pointing it out. Mmh can't edit the comment though ‍♂️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour ([UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)) in both cases as you pass the pointer which was not assigned with reference to the allocated valid memory, large enough to accommodate the scanned strings. As it is a UB it does not have to express itself in any particular way. So single variable version does not work as well.

```
int main(void)
{
   char x[10], y[10];
   char *a = x,*b = y;
   /* .... */
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
   
   char *a = malloc(10),*b = malloc(10);
   /* .... */
   free(a);
   free(b);
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
   char a[10], b[10];
   /* .... */
}
```